# Need to call function defined in .c to to another .c file

Tags: c

/****contacts.h***/

```
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};



struct Address {
    char street[41];
    int streetNumber;
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};

struct Numbers {

    char cell[10];
    char home[10];
    char business[10];
};


struct Contact {

    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    struct Numbers number;
};

void getName(struct Name *name);

void getAddress(struct Address *address);

void getNumbers(struct Numbers *number);

void getContact(struct Contact *contact);
```

/****Contacts.c****/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "contacts.h"
#include "contactHelpers.h"
void getName(struct Name *name)
{
        printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
        scanf(" %30[^\n]s",name->firstName);
        clearKeyboard();

        printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
        if(yes())
        {
                printf("Please enter the contact's middle initial(s): ");
                scanf(" %6[^\n]s",name->middleInitial);
                clearKeyboard();
        }
        else
        name->middleInitial[0]='\0';

        printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
        scanf(" %35[^\n]s",name->lastName);
        clearKeyboard();
}


void getAddress(struct Address *address)
{
        printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");
        address->streetNumber=getInt();

        printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
        scanf(" %40[^\n]s",address->street);
        clearKeyboard();

        printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");
        if(yes())
        {
                printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
                address->apartmentNumber=getInt();
        }
        else
        address->apartmentNumber='\0';

        printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
        scanf(" %7[^\n]s",address->postalCode);
        clearKeyboard();

        printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
        scanf(" %40[^\n]s",address->city);
        clearKeyboard();
}


void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers)
{
        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        getTenDigitPhone(numbers->cell);

        printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
        if(yes())
        {
                printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
               getTenDigitPhone(numbers->home);
        }
        else
        numbers->home[0]='\0';

        printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
        if(yes())
        {
                printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
               getTenDigitPhone(numbers->business);
        }
        else
        numbers->business[0]='\0';
}

    void getContact(struct Contact *contact)

{

  getName(&(contact->name));    
  getAddress(&(contact->address));

 getNumbers(&(contact->number));
}
```

/****contactHelpers.h*****/

```
#include"contacts.h"
void clearKeyboard(void);
void pause(void);
int getInt(void);
int getIntInRange(int, int);
int yes(void);
int menu(void); 
void ContactManagerSystem(void);
void getTenDigitPhone(char[11]);
int findContactIndex(const struct Contact contacts[], int size, const char cellNum[]);
void displayContactHeader(void);
void displayContactFooter(int);
void displayContact(const struct Contact* contacts);
void displayContacts(const struct Contact[], int);
void searchContacts(const struct Contact[], int);
void addContact(struct Contact[], int);
void updateContact(struct Contact[], int);
void deleteContact(struct Contact[], int);
void sortContacts(struct Contact[], int);
```

/****ContactsHelpers.c****/

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "contactHelpers.h"
#define MAXCONTACTS 5
int a=5;


void clearKeyboard(void)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n')   ; 
}

void pause(void)
{


    char ch;

        printf("(Press Enter to continue)");

        scanf("%c", &ch);

            if(ch==10)
            {
                clearKeyboard();
            }




}


int getInt(void)

{
    int i;
    char cha;
    printf("<Please enter an integer>: ");
    scanf("%d%c", &i,&cha);

        while (cha !='\n')
        {
            clearKeyboard();
            printf("*** INVALID INTEGER *** <Please enter an integer>: ");
            scanf("%d%c", &i,&cha);
        }


    return i;

}
int getIntInRange(int min, int max)


{

    int i;
    i=getInt();
    while(i< min || i > max)
    {
        printf("*** OUT OF RANGE *** <Enter a number between %d and %d>: ", min , max);
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }


}




int yes(void)
{

    char a,b;
    printf("<Please enter a character>: ");
    scanf("%c%c", &a,&b);

     while ((a !='Y' && a !='y' && a !='N' && a!='n') || (b!='\n'))
    { 
       if (b!='\n') ungetc(b, stdin),scanf("%*[^\n]%c", &b);
        a='n',b='\n';


            printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
            scanf("%c%c", &a,&b);

        }
        if (a =='Y' || a=='y')
        {
            return 1;
            printf("Contact Management System: terminated\n");


        }
        else 
        {
            if (a =='N' || a=='n')
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }

}



int menu(void)

{

    int i;
    printf("Contact Management System\n-------------------------\n1. Display contacts\n2. Add a contact\n3. Update a contact\n4. Delete a contact\n5. Search contacts by cell phone number\n6. Sort contacts by cell phone number\n0. Exit\n\nSelect an option:> ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    while (i<0 || i>6)
    {
        printf("*** OUT OF RANGE *** <Enter a number between 0 and 6>: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }
    return i;
}

void ContactManagerSystem(void)

{
    struct Contact contacts[a];
    int i=menu();
    int choice, exit =0;
    do
    {

    i = menu();
    switch(i)
    {
      case 0 :
        printf("Exit the program? (Y)es/(N)o: ");
        choice=yes();
        printf("\n");
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            printf("Contact Management System: terminated\n");
            exit = 1;
        }
        if (choice == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

      case 1 :
         printf("\n");
         displayContacts(contacts, a);
         pause();
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case 2 :
         printf("\n");
         addContact(contacts,a);
         pause();
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case 3 :
         printf("\n");
         updateContact(contacts,a);
         pause();
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case 4 :
         printf("\n");
         deleteContact(contacts,a);
         pause();
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case 5 :
        printf("\n");
         searchContacts(contacts,a);
         pause();
         printf("\n");
         break;
      case 6 :
         printf("\n");
         sortContacts(contacts,a);
         pause();
         printf("\n");
         break;

    }
 }
    while (exit == 0);

}

void getTenDigitPhone(char telNum[11])
{
    int needInput = 1;

    while (needInput == 1) {
        scanf("%10s", telNum);
        clearKeyboard();
        if (strlen(telNum) == 10)
            needInput = 0;
        else
            printf("Enter a 10-digit phone number: ");
    }
}


int findContactIndex(const struct Contact contacts[], int size, const char cellNum[])
{
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<=size; i++)
    {
        if( strcmp(contacts[i].number.cell, cellNum)==0)

        {
            return i;
        }
    }
        return -1;

}


void displayContactHeader(void)
{
    printf("+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|                              Contacts Listing                            |\n");
    printf("+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ \n");

}



void displayContactFooter(int total)
{
    printf("+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("Total contacts: %d\n\n", total);
}



void displayContact(const struct Contact* contacts)
{
     if(strcmp((*contacts).name.middleInitial,"")==0)
           printf(" %s %s\n",(*contacts).name.firstName,(*contacts).name.lastName);
        else
           printf(" %s %s %s\n",(*contacts).name.firstName,(*contacts).name.middleInitial,(*contacts).name.lastName);

        printf("    C: %-10s   H: %-10s   B: %-10s\n",(*contacts).number.cell,(*contacts).number.home,(*contacts).number.business);

        if((*contacts).address.apartmentNumber>0)
        printf("       %d %s, Apt# %d, %s, %s\n",(*contacts).address.streetNumber,(*contacts).address.street,(*contacts).address.apartmentNumber,(*contacts).address.city,(*contacts).address.postalCode);
        else
        printf("       %d %s, %s, %s\n",(*contacts).address.streetNumber,(*contacts).address.street,(*contacts).address.city,(*contacts).address.postalCode);
}


void displayContacts(const struct Contact contacts [], int size)
{
    int i, tot=0;
    displayContactHeader();
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
                if(strlen(contacts[i].number.cell)>0)
                {
                        tot=tot+1;
                        displayContact(&contacts[i]);
                }
        }
        displayContactFooter(tot);
}

void searchContacts(const struct Contact contacts[], int size)
{
    char num[11];
    int result;
    printf("Enter the cell number for the contact: ");
    getTenDigitPhone(num);
     result = findContactIndex(contacts,size, num);

        if(result== -1)
        {
                printf("\n");
                displayContact(&contacts[result]);
                printf("\n");
        }
        else
                printf("*** Contact NOT FOUND ***\n");


}


void addContact(struct Contact contacts [], int size)
{

        int i, available=-1;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
                if(strlen(contacts[i].number.cell)==0)
                {
                        available=i;
                        break;
                }
        }
        if(available>-1)
        {
                getContact(&contacts[available]);
                printf("--- New contact added! ---\n");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("*** ERROR: The contact list is full! ***");
                printf("\n");
        }
}

void updateContact(struct Contact contacts[], int size)
{
       char myNum[11];
        int myIndex;
        printf("Enter the cell number for the contact: ");
        getTenDigitPhone(myNum);
        myIndex = findContactIndex(contacts,size,myNum);

        if(myIndex>-1)
        {
                printf("\nContact found:\n");
                displayContact(&contacts[myIndex]);

                printf("\nDo you want to update the name? (y or n): ");
                if(yes())
                getName(&contacts[myIndex].name);

                printf("Do you want to update the address? (y or n): ");
                if(yes())
                getAddress(&contacts[myIndex].address);

                printf("Do you want to update the numbers? (y or n): ");
                if(yes())
                getNumbers(&contacts[myIndex].number);

                printf("--- Contact Updated! ---\n");
        }
        else
        printf("*** Contact NOT FOUND ***\n");
}

void deleteContact(struct Contact contacts [], int size)
{
    char num[11];
    char c;
    printf("Enter the cell number for the contact: ");
    scanf("%s%c", num), &c;
    getTenDigitPhone(num);

    int b = findContactIndex(contacts, size ,num);
    if(b == -1)
    {
        printf("*** Contact NOT FOUND ***\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nContact found:\n");
        displayContact(&contacts[b]);
        printf("CONFIRM: Delete this contact? (y or n): ");
        int c = yes();
        if( c == 1)
        {
            contacts[b].number.cell[0]='\0';
        }   printf("--- Contact deleted! ---\n");


    }

}

void sortContacts(struct Contact contacts[], int a)
{


    int i, j;
    struct Contact temp;

    for (i = 0; i < a - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (a - 1-i); j++)
        {
            if (contacts[j].number.cell < contacts[j + 1].number.cell)
            {
                temp = contacts[j];
                contacts[j] = contacts[j + 1];
                contacts[j + 1] = temp;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

/****MAIN****/

```
int main(void)
{
    ContactManagerSystem();

    return 0;
}
```

So in my code I have two .c files. In contacts.c I have defined a function getContact and I am using it in ContactHelpers.c. Although I am including a header file(that incldes the prototype of getcontact) in contactHelpers.c but it gives ma an error undefined reference to `getContact(Contact*)' . if I include contacts.c in contactHelpers.c it never stops compiling. please help me out

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162006/discussion-on-question-by-s-younas-need-to-call-function-defined-in-c-to-to-ano).

Answer (score 0):

How are you linking together your `ContactsHelpers.c`, `Contacts.c`, and your `main.c` ? Are you using Make with GCC, or some other compiler?

Whatever you do, **don't** `#include` another .c file. This will cause your compiler to compile recursively and try to compile the same code twice. Something else about your code that jumped out at me: No header guards. You are at risk of including the same information twice, breaking your program and causing errors. Wrap these lines around your header files.

```
#ifndef CONTACTS_H
#define CONTACTS_H

// content of contacts.h here...

#endif
```

And then for `contactHelpers.h`:

```
#ifndef CONTACTHELPERS_H
#define CONTACTHELPERS_H

// content of contactHelpers.h here...

#endif
```

If you're using Make to compile this, you will want your Makefile to be something like this. This is written with the assumption that `main()` is in `main.c`:

```
ContactsHelpers.o:
    gcc -o ContactsHelpers.o ContactsHelpers.c

Contacts.o:
    gcc -o Contacts.o Contacts.c

main.o:
    gcc -o main.o main.c

all:
    gcc -o Contacts ContactsHelpers.o Contacts.o main.o
```

Comment: On most modern compilers `#pragma once` is a sufficient include guard.